# VSTO Office Add In c# Reply to all doesn’t always show/fire

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I’m building an add in for `Outlook 2010`, when a user clicks `Reply` to all I want a message box to show saying  'Are you sure?'. With so many users in our organisation too many click `Reply` to all not realising what they’re doing.

This may look as overkill but we plan to count the number of recipients and have this show if its greater than `X`.

I’m using the following code, for some reason the message box only either shows once, or will randomly show each time.

Can anyone help?

```
private Outlook.Application _application = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    _application.ItemLoad += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(_application_ItemLoad);
}

private void GenerateItemMessage(object item, string operation)
{
    MailItem mi = item as Outlook.MailItem;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("MailItem {0} will be {1}", mi.Subject, operation));
}

private void ThisAddIn_ReplyAll(object item, ref bool cancel)
{
    GenerateItemMessage(item, "ReplyToAll");
}

private void _application_ItemLoad(object Item)
{
    ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)Item).ReplyAll += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(ThisAddIn_ReplyAll);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must keep the source object alive if you want to handle events:

```
private void GenerateItemMessage(object item, string operation)
{
    MailItem mi = item as Outlook.MailItem;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("MailItem {0} will be {1}", mi.Subject, operation));
}
```

The scope of `mi` object is limited by the method where it is declared. The `GC` can swipe it from the heap at any point of time. So, you need to declare it at the global scope:

```
MailItem mi = null;
private void GenerateItemMessage(object item, string operation)
{
    mi = item as Outlook.MailItem;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("MailItem {0} will be {1}", mi.Subject, operation));
}
```

Or you may consider maintaining a list of objects if you going to handle many of them simultaneously.

You should DO so everywhere in the code, for example, looks like you didn't do so for the following sample:

```
private void _application_ItemLoad(object Item)
{
    ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)Item).ReplyAll += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(ThisAddIn_ReplyAll);
}
```

You will not get the `ReplyAll` event fire after the `_application_ItemLoad` method finishes. You need to keep objects alive if you want to get events fired:

```
Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event _item;
private void _application_ItemLoad(object Item)
{
    _item = (Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)Item;
    _item.ReplyAll += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(ThisAddIn_ReplyAll);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. By changing my code to your suggestion it’s now working more regularly, but still on occasion not firing. With the GC are you sayin this may never fully work?

Comment: Eugene the one you’ve written above where mi is declared outside of the generate message section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you expand on why this happens? Why when we click reply all again, is ThisAddIn_ReplyAll not called again?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ItemLoad` (or in addition to), try to trap the `Explorer.SelectionChange` event and set up `ReplyAll` events handlers on the selected items.